# There was an error generating the XML document

Tags: c#, wpf, xml-serialization

hi i have the following code to perform xml serialization:

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string savepath;
            SaveFileDialog DialogSave = new SaveFileDialog();
            // Default file extension
            DialogSave.DefaultExt = "txt";
            // Available file extensions
            DialogSave.Filter = "XML file (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            // Adds a extension if the user does not
            DialogSave.AddExtension = true;
            // Restores the selected directory, next time
            DialogSave.RestoreDirectory = true;
            // Dialog title
            DialogSave.Title = "Where do you want to save the file?";
            // Startup directory
            DialogSave.InitialDirectory = @"C:/";
            DialogSave.ShowDialog();
            savepath = DialogSave.FileName;
            DialogSave.Dispose();
            DialogSave = null;

            FormSaving abc = new FormSaving();
            if (MajorversionresultLabel != null && MajorversionresultLabel.Content != null && MajorversionLabel.Content.ToString() != string.Empty)
            abc.Majorversion = MajorversionresultLabel.Content.ToString();
            //abc.Minorversion = MinorversionresultLabel.Content.ToString();
            //abc.Projectnumber = ProjectnumberresultLabel.Content.ToString();
            //abc.Buildnumber = BuildnumberresultLabel.Content.ToString();
            //abc.Previousbuildversion = PreviousbuildversionresultLabel.Content.ToString();
            abc.Startzbuildfrom = StartzbuildfromcomboBox.SelectedItem;

            using (Stream savestream = new FileStream(savepath, FileMode.Create))
            {

                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FormSaving));
                    serializer.Serialize(savestream, abc);
            }



        }
```

the error "There was an error generating the XML document" occurs at `serializer.Serialize(savestream, abc);`

my form saving class:

```
public class FormSaving
        {

            public string Majorversion
            {
                get;

                set;

            }
            public string Minorversion
            {
                get;

                set;

            }
            public string Projectnumber
            {
                get;

                set;

            }
            public string Buildnumber
            {
                get;

                set;

            }
            public string Previousbuildversion
            {
                get;

                set;

            }
            public object Startzbuildfrom
            {
                get;

                set;
            }
    }
```

can anyone help me fix this?

EDIT:

i tried this but it doesnt work as well:

under "save button"

```
abc.Startzbuildfrom = StartzbuildfromcomboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

under "load button"

```
StartzbuildfromcomboBox.SelectedItem = abc.Startzbuildfrom;
```

here is how i populate my combobox items:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" Margin="577,72,497,0" Name="StartzbuildfromcomboBox" VerticalAlignment="Top"><ComboBoxItem>library</ComboBoxItem></ComboBox>
```

Comment: Is FormSaving a custom class that you've defined? I haven't heard of it before and can't find any reference to it on Google. If it is, could you please post it, or if not, give a link to where I can find more information on it. Thanks.

Comment: @joshhendo hi, i just edited adding the class. thanks

Comment: minus 1.  answer not marked as correct, after sorting through the many lines of code, it is clear what is going on, however for this to be a good SO question, the answer should clearly indicate insight into the problem and clear solution.  The biggest problem with this entire post is that a person following the link here would have a difficult time figuring out how to solve this for themselves.  Without these changes, this post adds little to the SO knowledgebase, and adds more noise than content.

Comment: @MedicineMan what are u talking about? don't quite get you

Comment: first: please mark the correct answer as correct.

Comment: second: please restate your answer so that it answers the question clearly and concisely.  An explanation of the solution using words and sentences with correct grammar and punctuation would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Although `object` is technically a serializable type, the concrete type of Startzbuildfrom is obscured. In fact, you are trying to serialize a ComboBoxItem, which is not serializable. Try using a serializable type for the Startzbuildfrom property and set its value using the SelectedValue property of the combo box, not the SelectedItem property.

Comment: hi paul thanks for the information, i didn't know that. so if i were to serialize a combobox selected item how should i go about doing that?

Comment: object is C# keyword which is an alias to Object type and it is serializable.

Comment: What is the actual type of the data that is bound to the Value Member of the list box? You should use that for the type of the Startzbuildfrom property (as long as it is serializable). Also, use SelectedValue rather than SelectedItem. I've updated my answer. Sorry the original was incomplete and had an error.

Comment: @Vijay yes, my original answer was in error. Object is serializable.

Answer (score 0):

What is the data source for StartzbuildcomboBox?

And more specifically what is the type of DataItem of each StartzbuildcomboBox.SelectedItem?

Can you also include the InnerException?

Most possible reason could be that Startzbuildfrom (shouldn't it be StartzBuildFrom?) is assigned to a type which the XmlSerializer has no idea about.

If you know the type then decorate FormSaving with XmlInclude.

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(type-of-selected-combobox-selected-item))]
public class FormSaving
{
  .........
```

Comment: hi vijay, thanks for your input. i do not have any real datasource. what i did was this in my xaml: <ComboBox Height="23" Margin="577,70,497,0" Name="StartzbuildcomboBox" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <ComboBoxItem>library</ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox> and i am not sure about dataitem as well. What is innerexception?

Comment: Quick fix: Set the Startzbuildfrom type to String instead of Object. And while assigning abc.Startzbuildfrom = StartzbuildcomboBox.SelectedItem.ToString(); this should work.

Comment: upon loading, the combobox item is not still not selected :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved,

i tried this:

```
public class FormSaving
        {
            ...

            public int Startzbuildfrom
            {
                get;

                set;
            }


        }
...
abc.Startzbuildfrom = StartzbuildfromcomboBox.SelectedIndex;

...
StartzbuildfromcomboBox.SelectedIndex = abc.Startzbuildfrom;
```